# How to pass data from Flask to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I want to use this JavaScript library to show tables (data I retrieve from MySQL): 
http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/data#array

I use Flask as backend server. I need to send the data back to a JavaScript file since the "magic" occurs there.

Example of the page:

```
var tableData = [
    {id:1, name:"Billy Bob", age:"12", gender:"male", height:1, col:"red", dob:"", cheese:1},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", gender:"female", height:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", cheese:true},
]

table.setData(tableData);
```

So I try to make my MySQL query result return to JavaScript and then I use it with the above-mentioned code.
Currently Flask returns JSON and it shows in the browser, but I want to catch it in JavaScript.
I know I should use AJAX, but somehow it doesn't work.

Any help someone? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a library such as jQuery, which supports AJAX. You then need to have a Python script you can call that will return the `tableData` structure as a `JSON` string. This would be your Flask backend script returning a list of dictionaries, which you already have. Then your JavaScript would be:

```
$.getJSON(url_of_flask_script, function(tableData) {
    table.setData(tableData)
    .then(function(){
        //run code after table has been successfuly updated
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        //handle error loading data
    });
});
```